# dojo- clusteredcolumn chart datalabels as excel

Tags: javascript, excel, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm using the dojo to generate charts. I'm generating chart ClusteredColumn.I intend to enter datalabels as in Excel, however I find no solution. Anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. But if you look at this section of the dojox charting doc (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/charting.html#style-on-lines-areas-bars-columns-bubble-pie-plots) in the "about labels" paragraph you'll find a way to specificy data lables for columns/bars. Maybe it will help you.